# how to SET sql_safe_updates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I can not `SET sql_safe_updates` in PHP

```
$query = "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'";
```

the `.$row[Value']` only shows `OFF`.

Did I need to change MYSQL server setting or php?

```
 if (!$mysqli->query("SET sql_safe_updates = 1" )) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);          
    }
```

---

after few comment to this post , 

 I found

`UPDATE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES SET VARIABLE_NAME = "ON" WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = sql_safe_updates`

But fail again

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Comment: If you want to use [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) use `update TABLE set COLUMN = COLUMN` type of syntax, with an optional `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Table variables doesn't exist

Comment: @Fred-ii- true, but not for [Updating Server Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates)

Comment: What error do you get when you execute `SET sql_safe_updates = 1`?